# How to deselect the select all checkbox when i am deselecting even 1 checkbox in android

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I want functionality in my project where on a click of select all checkbox all the checkbox in the list must get selected and on deselect of checkbox all the other checkbox must get deselected. I have achieved this functionality by doing this:

```
/*in my main activity i have done this*/

  cbSelectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                for (int i = 0; i < resumeSearchList.size(); i++) {
                    resumeSearchList.get(i).setSelected(cbSelectAll.isChecked());
                }
                cvSearchResultListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

and in adapter class I have done this..

```
holder.cbSelect.setChecked(dataList.get(position).isSelected());
```

Now my problem is whenever I will unchecked any checkbox in the list the select all button must get unchecked. Please help

thanks in advance

Comment: add a check change listener for your list's checkbox too and when you get value false uncheck your select all checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `OnCheckedChangeListener` on `holder.cbSelect.` in your adapter.

```
holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
                    // here you can call listener to get notified 
            }
        });
    }
```

You can have `listener` to get notified in your `Activity.`

For adding listener,

**1. Create an `interface`:**

```
public interface OnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener {
    void onMyCheckBoxCheckedChange();
}
```

**2. Add parameter in your constructor of Adapter:**

```
private OnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener mOnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener;

    public YourAdapter(..., ..., OnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener onMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener) {
            mOnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener = onMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener;
        }
```

**3. Call interface where you want to notify:**

```
holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
                    mOnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener.onMyCheckBoxCheckedChange(); 
            }
        });
    }
```

**4. Set adapter from your activity:**

```
yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(..., ..., new OnMyCheckBoxCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyCheckBoxCheckedChange() {
        // you will get notified here.
    }
}));
```

Comment: how to set the listener here..can you pleas explain more?